# Using socket.io to emit and array

Tags: arrays, socket.io, emit

So I have an array I would like to send to all users with socket io.

I'm trying to create an array of random numbers and then copy that array into all other clients. Here's the code:

Server Side:

```
var worldMapVar = {}; 

socket.on('worldMapData', function (data9) {
    io.sockets.emit('worldMapDataUpdated',{
        worldMapVar: data9
    });
});
```

Client Side:

```
//The array I want to send. The r's are all random numbers.
var worldMap = [

 [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
 [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
 [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
 [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
 [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
 [1, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, 1],
 [1, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, 1],
 [1, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, 1],
 [1, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, 1],
 [1, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, 1],
 [1, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, 1],
 [1, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, 1],
 [1, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, 1],
 [1, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, 1],
 [1, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, 1],
 [1, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, 1],
 [1, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, 0, 0, 0, 0, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, 1],
 [1, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, 0, 0, 0, 0, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, 1],
 [1, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, 0, 0, 0, 0, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, 1],
 [1, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, 0, 0, 0, 0, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, 1],
 [1, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, 1],
 [1, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, 1],
 [1, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, 1],
 [1, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, 1],
 [1, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, 1],
 [1, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, 1],
 [1, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, 1],
 [1, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, 1],
 [1, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, 1],
 [1, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, 1],
 [1, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, 1],
 [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
 [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
 [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
 [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
 [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
];


//emitting the array
for (var i = 0; i < worldMap.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < worldMap[0].length; j++) {

   socket.emit('worldMapData', { worldMapVar: worldMap[i][j] });

  }
 }


//setting the array equal to the original array on all other clients

socket.on('worldMapDataUpdated', function (data9) {
 var worldMapVar = [];

 worldMapVar.push(data9);

 for (var i = 0; i < worldMap.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < worldMap[0].length; j++) {
   if (worldMap[i][j] === r) {
    worldMap[i][j] = worldMapVar;
   }
  }
 }
 // console.log(worldMap);
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could just send your array in one emit (you dont have to loop through it) :

```
socket.emit('worldMapData', { worldMapVar: worldMap});
```

This will send your whole array at once.